# set bordor-ed column to fill full height in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://bootply.com/84458

the border length of col-md-4 doesn't reach until the bottom of the column, I can't make it to certain height in css because it will broke when it got resized, since bootstrap is responsive..

I want the content of the 3 column appear in a 'box'

Comment: Do you mean `height:100%` ? -- See updated Bootply: http://bootply.com/84458

Comment: @Skelly I tried that way, it ruined when it got resized, my content is dynamic